# Override Ivy Resolver

Tags: ivy

I have a project with an ivysettings.xml that is shared amongst developers.  It works, but I am on a corporate network that makes resolving from external locations slow.  Other developers on the project are on different networks that cannot resolve from my corporate network's internal nexus.

I would like to have some sort of global ivysettings.xml that will override the project's ivysettings.xml's resolver chain.

Can I do that, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you have an `ivysettings.xml` where you define a `mychain` chain containing `myresolver` resolver, you can do the following to override your chain structure in another ivy settings file:

```
<ivysettings>
   <include file="ivysettings.xml"/>
   <resolvers>
      <chain name="mychain"  >
         <resolver ref="myresolver"/>
         <!-- Add more resolvers to your original chain -->
      </chain>
   </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```